# How to require users not to be logged in for comments on single page only?

Tags: comments

I am trying to make my own guestbook out of default comments, but I normally require users to be logged in.

In this case, I need WP not to require it. Is there a way to do it for single page?

Thank you

Comment: Just an FYI but if you do this approach I hope you have a lot of time on your hands so you can manage all your spam comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremely not tested, based on overriding the global "users must login to comment" option (comment_registration) for a specific post

```
function wpse208664_option_comment_registration($v) {
  if (is_single() && (get_the_ID() == your specific post ID))
    $v = 0;
  return $v;
}

add_filter('option_comment_registration', 'wpse208664_option_comment_registration');
```